# How to Disable Window from Automatically Maximizing?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window-resize

I have a window that i have set ResizeMode=NoResize and got rid of all the title bar and buttons but the problem is when window is dragged to the top of the screen it maximizes and i am not able to stop that. Does any one faced this problem before where i have code for maximize and minimize the window to a certain width and height.

this is a sample code

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
    x:Class="Custom_title_bar.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" 
    Background="Transparent" mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    MinHeight="180" MinWidth="180"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" WindowState="Normal">
<Grid Name="Main" >
   <Border Name="MainWindow" CornerRadius="1" Background="White"   
    BorderBrush="AliceBlue" MouseDown="move_window"  >
      <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
           <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="26">
              <Border CornerRadius="1">
                 <Border.Background>
                     <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="BurlyWood" Offset="0.25"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Bisque" Offset="0.5"/>
                      </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.Background>
                 <Grid>
                   <DockPanel>  
                    <Image  MouseDown="MINIMIZE" 
                     Source="/Custom%20title%20bar;component/Images/minimize.png" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                     <Image  MouseDown="MAX_RESTORE" 
                      Source="/Custom%20title%20bar;component/Images/Restore.png"                   
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                      <Image  MouseDown="EXIT" 
                      Source="/Custom%20title%20bar;component/Images/close.png"  />
                       <TextBlock/>
                    </DockPanel>
                 </Grid>
            </Border>
         </DockPanel>
       </DockPanel>
      </Grid>
     </Border>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show what mouse_move() does?  And what is your Windows version?

Comment: was using user32.dll functions but changed it to this.DragMove it helped me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you set your `MaxHeight`/`MaxWidth` properties?

Since your default size seems to be `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, it might be best to set the `MaxHeight`/`MaxWidth` in the `Loaded` event of your `Window`

```
this.MaxHeight = this.ActualHeight;
this.MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth;
```

Comment: thanks I solved it but little bit different way then yours made the height and width local properties and got ActualHeight and then when it is maximized using System.Windows.SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth and height resizing it. Thanks again for your help.